# Magento extension settings

Tags: php, magento

How can I add "settings" to a Magento extension? Like, give it a set of credentials unique to each "instance", which users set upon installation (by editing the XML).

I've seen by reading [this](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/) you have to create a "global" settings file, `system.xml`, but I'd prefer to have just a drop-in file, to make installation easier.

Any help? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Read this tutorial it will explain it to you in detail:

http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Let me know if you have any questions as you go along, but it is very well explained in that link.